# Member stream consumer failed removing it from group

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Streams application that throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "<StreamsApp>-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=topic1, partition=0, offset=1
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:240)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:94)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:411)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:918)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:798)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:750)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:720)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [0_0] Abort sending since an error caught with a previous record (key null value {...} timestamp 1530812658459) to topic topic2 due to Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
You can increase producer parameter `retries` and `retry.backoff.ms` to avoid this error.
```

In Streams app I have the following **configs**:

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG), 5);
props.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG), 300000);
props.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG), 300000);
```

I checked **kafka broker logs** (I have a single kafka broker) and see the following logs related to this:

```
INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Member <StreamsApp>-StreamThread-1-consumer-49d0a5b3-be2a-4b5c-a4ab-ced7a2484a02 in group <StreamsApp> has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-07-03 14:39:23,893] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Preparing to rebalance group <StreamsApp> with old generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-46) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-07-03 14:39:23,893] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Group <StreamsApp> with generation 2 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-46) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

I read somewhere that its related to consumer not calling `poll()` for quite some time and hence it is kicked out by the consumer coordinator and  now the new consumer uses heartbeat as the failure detection protocol. I am not sure if this can be the reason since I am using `Kafka version 1.1.0` and `streams version 1.1.0` as well.

How can I avoid this failure scenario? For now I have to restart streams application every time this happens.

**UPDATE-1:**

I am trying to handle this `StreamsException` by enclosing the main in `try-catch` block but I cant catch the exception. What can be the reason for it and how can I catch it and exit the application? Currently streams-app is in a halt state and not doing anything after this exception.

**UPDATE-2:**

Following [this](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/write-streams.html#using-kafka-streams-within-your-application-code) and [this](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/write-streams.html#using-kafka-streams-within-your-application-code) I have updated my code to this:

```
final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

streams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((Thread thread, Throwable throwable) -> {
    log.error("EXITTING");
    log.error(throwable.getMessage());
    streams.close(5 ,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    latch.countDown();
    System.exit(-1);            
});
```

Now the exception is handled and logged. However, Streams app is not exited (its still running in terminal in halt state). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't kill it. I have to kill it by getting `pid` of the process and calling `kill` on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have stopped streams app and exited it.

```
final Topology topology = builder.build();
final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

streams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((Thread thread, Throwable throwable) -> {
    log.error("EXITING");
    log.error(throwable.getMessage());
    latch.countDown();          
});

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));

try {
    streams.start();
    latch.await();
} catch (Throwable e) {
    log.info("Exitting apllication with status code 1");
    System.exit(1);
}

log.info("Exitting apllication with status code 0");
streams.close(5 ,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.exit(0);
```

For the exception and related broker logs:

Reduce `max.poll.records` so `poll()` is called more often. (Confluent help forum).

I haven't tried this yet. Will update once I test this out.

Comment: Did reducing `max.poll.records` improve the situation?

Comment: Yes it did. I configured it to a lower number based on the processing time per event.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem.Even restarting the process couldn't get consumers to join in.I have to restart this Kafka every time for all the consumers.I adjusted the relevant configuration, but the problem continued to occur with consumers when a large number of messages were written.
props.put("max.poll.interval.ms",30*60*1000); props.put("session.timeout.ms",100000); props.put("max.poll.records",100);
I use manual submission, and when I have consumed the message and processed it, I submit the offset. However, I usually use only a few seconds for the whole transaction, but I still set it to 30 minutes. Expect someone to tell me the question.